# Make Custom Taxonomy Category Use Parent Template

Tags: custom-taxonomy, templates

I have a Wordpress custom post type set up in my `functions.php` called "Research"

I have a custom taxonomy called "Classifications"

Under that taxonomy I have the terms/categories:

```
Old Research (parent) 
--- sub cat 1 
--- sub cat 2
```

I have created the file "taxonomy-Classifications-oldresearch.php" which successfully changes the parent layout for me. However, it does not hold the layout in the sub categories. The sub-category pages revert to another file `taxonomy-Classifications.php`

I can alter it by also creating `taxonomy-Classifications-subcat1-oldresearch.php` but I will have a lot of sub categories that I want to use ONE template for - the parent cat template. This way I don't have to create a new template file for every new category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hook into `template_include` filter

```
add_filter('template_include', 'research_term_template');

function research_term_template( $template ) {
  if ( is_tax('classifications') ) {
    $parent = get_term_by('slug', 'oldresearch', 'classifications');
    // to improve performance you can hardcoding 'oldresearch' term id
    // $parent = 12;
    if ( term_is_ancestor_of( $parent, get_queried_object(), 'classifications' ) )
       return get_template_directory() . '/taxonomy-Classifications-oldresearch.php';
  }
  return $template;
}
```

Comment: Simply great solution.

Comment: thanks, @cybnet. 'template_include' is great, often underestimated, filter.

Comment: Would this go in my functions file or in one of the template files?

Comment: functions.php @user2612111

Comment: okay. I have inserted the code, but Dreamweaver is giving me an error in code at the return get_template_directory() line.

Comment: That Dreamweaver error is because is not loading wordpress engine, when you have get_template_directory() in Wordpress context it will works.

Comment: oh, okay. I tried but then the site returns: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_RETURN

Comment: here is the code in my functions.php https://www.dropbox.com/s/52s4s2u4g76jvyq/screencap%20functions.jpg
I'm sure I'm just not place it right? *PHP newb* :(

Comment: I forgot a ')'. Check again the code @user2612111

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much!!! That works :-)
Now, is there any add on's where I can make all the SINGLE posts under the term oldresearch and any sub-terms to use the a specific template as well? Should I post this as another question?

Comment: Yes, ask another question. is hard answer in comments. @user2612111

Answer (score 0):

Change template file name taxonomy-Classifications-oldresearch.php to taxonomy-Classifications.php so that it will work for both parent and child terms of Classifications custom taxonomy.

Comment: Hi, that would work, but I need the oldresearch category to look difference than taxonomy-Classifications.php and have a different sidebar.

Comment: Then for oldresearch category use taxonomy-Classifications-oldresearch.php template and for others categories use taxonomy-Classifications.php template.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the [taxonomy templates hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Taxonomies_display) documentation seems like it is working as expected. The file `taxonomy-Classifications-oldresearch.php` is specific for `oldresearch` term and that file won't be used by any other term. The file taxonomy-Classifications.php will be used by all terms of `Classifications` taxonomy except by the terms with a specific template like `taxonomy-Classifications-oldresearch.php`.

The template taxonomy hierarchy is as follow:

1. A term-specific template is the first template used by Wordpress (in this case `taxonomy-Classifications-oldresearch.php`).
2. If no term-specific template is found, then wordpress will use taxonomy-spceific template (in this case `taxonomy-Classifications.php`).
3. If no taxonomy-specific template is found, then wordpress will use a general template for all taxonomies (taxonomy.php).
4. If taxonomy.php is not found, wordpress will use the archive.php template.
5. Finally, if archive.php is not found Wordpress will use index.php.

To alter this behaviour you can check the parent of the current term and use [get_template_part()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) function or include/requiere to load the template you want. There is no other solution, I think. For example, in `taxonomy-Classifications.php`:

```
$term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var('term'), 'Classifications' );
if($term->parent == 'your_oldresearch_term_ID'){
   inclue(get_template_directory().'/taxonomy-Classifications-oldresearch.php');
} else {
  .....
  .....
}
```

Comment: Why wont the subcategories under Old Research default to taxonomy-Classifications-oldresearch.php instead of taxonomy-Classifications.php?

Comment: beacuse `oldresearch` is a term, not the taxonomy, and a term-specific template is the first template used (in this case `taxonomy-Classifications-oldresearch.php`). See my edited answer, I've added more explanation.

Comment: Thanks, that does help shed some light on the terms I was using. I guess I don't know why the child terms of oldresearch don't use it's template.

Comment: I would love to mark your question as correct as it was helpful, but I really dont have a solution to my problem still. I don't need to have a bunch of templates for my sub-terms. I only want one.

Comment: I think you should read again my answer. I've added more.

Comment: Hi Thank you! It seems like this might work if I can just be a little more PHP savvy. I suppose my template content goes where the ...... are inside else {} ?

PS... there is a "d" missing in "include" line 3

Comment: sorry for the missing 'd' but please, use the solution suggested by @G.M. My suggested solution will make the job but the other answer is really the best option.

Comment: oh no worries, I caught it right away. I'm sorry I can't say your answer was useful as I don't have enough rep points yet. I really appreciate your help with this though. :-) I am trying to figure out G.M's solution.

Answer (score 0):

In `taxonomy-Classifications.php` you can add some logic to check the term and then include a loop template specific to that term.

```
// seudo-code logic example
if Classifications,  
    use loop-classifactions.php  

else if Classifications -> Old Research,  
    use loop-classifications-oldresearch.php

else if Classifications -> Old Research -> Child Term,  
    use loop-classifications-oldresearch-child.php
```

I believe this is the solution you are after.
[Get template part based on custom taxonomy term](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/108507/get-template-part-based-on-custom-taxonomy-term)