# Make Terms Under Custom Taxonomy Use Specific Single.php Template

Tags: customization, templates, terms

Yesterday some wonderful people helped me solve the issue here about [templates for custom taxonomy terms](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/113075/make-custom-taxonomy-category-use-parent-template).

Now I have a related question. Again, I have a custom post type set up in my functions.php called "Research"

I have a custom taxonomy called "Classifications"

Under that taxonomy I have the terms:

oldresearch (parent) 
--- subcat1 
--- subcat2

I need all the single pages under this term "Old Research" and in the sub cats to use one template. I already have a single-research.php that is being use elsewhere. So that's not my preferred option. Any ideas? Please be detailed as I'm a PHP newb - sorry. lol Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't found a perfect solution yet, as I'd hoped to do some automated call for the template in the functions.php or template file, I have found a workaround.

I'm using the "[custom post template](http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-template/other_notes/)" plugin. Out of the box this plug in does not support CPT's, however, you can place the code below in your functions.php file to make it work with CPT's.

```
/**
 * Hooks the WP cpt_post_types filter 
 *
 * @param array $post_types An array of post type names that the templates be used by
 * @return array The array of post type names that the templates be used by
 **/
function my_cpt_post_types( $post_types ) {
    $post_types[] = 'YOURPOSTTYPENAME1';
    $post_types[] = 'YOURPOSTTYPENAME2';
    return $post_types;
}
add_filter( 'cpt_post_types', 'my_cpt_post_types' );
```

On your post edit screen, select the post template you have created. http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-template/