# Make child taxonomy categories use a set template

Tags: custom-taxonomy, templates

I have a custom taxonomy called product-categories. Currently all categories use the master template (taxonomy-product-categories.php).

The category tree is roughly as follows.

```
Products 
- Cheese
-- Types of Cheese
--- Cheddar
--- Brie
--- Cheshire
-- Types of Milk
--- Cows Cheese
--- Goats Cheese
- Cakes
- Category
```

I want to set it so that all categories, including sub_categories in the cheese section of the tree use a cheese template (taxonomy-product-categories-cheese.php).  With other templates for the other areas.

I've found a two year old post which appears to be the solution but does not appear to do anything.

[Make Custom Taxonomy Category Use Parent Template](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/113075/make-custom-taxonomy-category-use-parent-template)

I've added the following to my functions.php

```
add_filter('template_include', 'cheese_term_template');

function cheese_term_template( $template ) {
  if ( is_tax('classifications') ) {
    // $parent = get_term_by('slug', 'cheese', 'classifications');
    $parent = 13;
    if ( term_is_ancestor_of( $parent, get_queried_object(), 'classifications' ) )
       return get_template_directory() . '/taxonomy-product-categories-cheese.php';
  }
  return $template;
}
```

I though that it was looking at the top level category instead but when I did some tests it didn't work with that either. I wonder if it was because the taxonomy name has a hyphen in it.

I'd appreciate any help... Thanks

Comment: Is your taxonomy *called* `classifications` or is it called `product-categories` ? The latter sounds like the rewrite slug.

Comment: Ahhh thank you... I didn't realise that "classifications" should have been the taxonomy name...  I either looked at it for too long or it just looked like it was supposed to be there. I changed "classifications" to "product-categories" and it all started to work..

Answer (score 2):

WordPress has a [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) - [specifically for taxonomies and terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#custom-taxonomies). So what template name you want should follow along the lines of:

`taxonomy-{$taxonomy}-{$term-slug}.php`

In your case:

`taxonomy-classifications-cheese.php`

This will grab onto the `cheese` category and display this specific template. I'm not entirely sure if this will also catch child categories ( I would test the above first before trying the below ) but if it does not you can:

```
function cheese_template_redirect( $template ) {

    if ( is_tax( 'classifications' ) ) {
        $term   = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );
        $cheese = 13;   // This should be "Cheese" Category
        if ( term_is_ancestor_of( $cheese, $term->term_id, 'classifications' ) ) {
            $new_template = locate_template( array( 'taxonomy-classifications-cheese.php' ) );
            if ( '' != $new_template ) {
                return $new_template ;
            }
        }
    }

    return $template;
}
add_filter( 'template_include', 'cheese_template_redirect', 99 );
```

It looks like your issue is that you're using the actual taxonomy rewrite slug, which we don't want to use. I haven't tested the above code but if it doesn't work or if you run into issues, let me know.

Comment: I've not tested the above as the previous comment made me realise my error. Thank you.