# Get template part using a custom taxonomy term

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, terms, get-template-part

I've been using the following code to get a template part based on the parent term. It was working fine until I updated WordPress to v4.4 earlier today. Since updating if there is also a child term selected it no longer works to bring in the template part.

Any ideas? I'm tearing my hair out.

```
<?php

$terms = get_the_terms( $post->id, 'type', array( 'parent' => 0 ) );
$terms_slugs = array();
foreach( $terms as $term ) {
    $terms_slugs[] = $term->slug;
}

if( !empty($terms_slugs) ) :
  get_template_part( 'blocks/block', array_pop($terms_slugs) );
else : endif;

?>
```

Edit: Solved it! Changing array_pop to array_shift. No idea what the difference is or why array_pop would suddenly stop working. Phew!

Comment: I'm assuming your file is: `theme-name/blocks/block-termname`? How does the term-slug look, can you give us an example?

Comment: File is theme-name/blocks/block-written-in-stone and the term slug is written-in-stone

Comment: What does "if there is also a child term selected " mean? Where does this fail? With `get_the_terms()`? With `get_template_part()`? Can you narrow this down?

Comment: If the parent category is the only category selected then it works no problem, but if I select a second sub category (child) then it fails to use the template part. It's really odd, as this was working before I upgraded WP this morning.

Comment: Please do not edit the solution into the question.

Comment: [In this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/108510/77054) `array_pop` works.

Answer (score 1):

leanda reports that the problem has been resolved:

> Solved it by changing `array_pop` to `array_shift`.