# Show template part if part of term

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, terms

I'm not an educated programmer, but usually i can put existing code together so it works the way i want it to. But this time i'm lost, i feel like i've tried everything.

I'm trying to only show a template part if the product is part of a specific term. This is one of the numerous code snippets i've tried.

I hope it makes sense to what i'm trying if not i'll answer any questions :)

```
 $taxonomy = taxonomy_exists( 'produkttype' );
 if ( $term = 'pude' && $term = 'senge' ) {
      echo get_template_part( 'partials/sections/section', 'trustpilot' );
    }
```

Comment: Use the [`get_the_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/) function 
instead of [`taxonomy_exists()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/taxonomy_exists). 
In your code you only check if the term has been defined, not if it is assigned/associated to the post.
Look at accepted answer in [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/108507/get-template-part-based-on-custom-taxonomy-term?rq=1) question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had tried the get_the_terms, just not in the correct way. I now know what the taxonomy_exists () does, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
if( has_term('pude', 'produkttype') || has_term('senge', 'produkttype')) {

   get_template_part( 'partials/sections/section', 'trustpilot' );

}
```

Comment: This seems to work, thank you very much for your fast reply!

Comment: @webmastertouche great, consider marking it as right answer.

Comment: Yes of course, it's done :)